# ASP.NET Web API 2 Child entities missing when serialized

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, web-services, entity-framework-6, asp.net-web-api2

I am currently building an angular website and using Web Api 2 as my data service.

I have encountered a issue with populating child entities when i call a http get method. The child entities (fields) does not appear in the Json response.

```
     //Fetch records by page size
    public ICollection<CompanyStatDomainModel> GetRecordsByPageSize(int page)
    {
        const int pgeSize = 20;

        var result = _companyStatRepo.AllIncluding(c => c.CompanyDomainModel, c => c.RatingDomainModels)
            .OrderBy(c => c.CompanyStatId).Skip(page * pgeSize).Take(pgeSize).ToList();

        return result;
    }
```

CONTROLLER

```
   public ICollection<CompanyStatDomainModel> GetRecordsByPageSize(int page)
   {
       var companyStatService = new CompanyStatService();

       return companyStatService.GetRecordsByPageSize(page);
   }
```

WebApiConfig.cs

```
     var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
        json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
        config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
```

Comment: Have you narrowed this down to a formatting issue? Set a breakpoint on `return result;`. Do you have a valid collection at this point?

Comment: Yes i have, the result returns all three tables. However the json result only shows the data for the parent table.

Comment: Try instead of returning `ICollection<T>`, change your method call to `public IHttpActionResult GetRecordsByPageSize(int page)`. And in that, return the following => `return Ok(result);` Let me know if that makes a difference?

Comment: I have done that but i am getting an error. Please see below  //Fetch records by page size
        public IHttpActionResult GetRecordsByPageSize(int page)
        {
            const int pgeSize = 20;

            var result = _companyStatRepo.AllIncluding(c => c.CompanyDomainModel, c => c.RatingDomainModels)
                .OrderBy(c => c.CompanyStatId).Skip(page * pgeSize).Take(pgeSize).ToList();

            return Ok(result);
        }

Comment: What is the error? Share you js code

Comment: Error is Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.Http.IHttpActionResult' to 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<CompanyStatDomainModel>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) CompanyStatController.cs

Comment: Ah I see. I thought the first block of code was your controller. Try swapping them around. `IHttpActionResult` should be on your controller and wrap `ok()` with the result from `GetRecordsByPageSize`

Comment: Just tried that. No error, same result. The child entities does not appear in the results.

Comment: Next step I would take would to run a [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) trace- then share your angularjs code

Comment: Just FYI. The company table and Rating Table are forign keys on the CompanyStat table. I am trying to access the field from the company table and rating table

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77515/discussion-between-erkan-demir-and-sal-niro).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to solve this kind of problem is by manually projecting the results of the EF query to the desired structure, something like

```
var result = _companyStatRepo
  .AllIncluding(c => c.CompanyDomainModel, c => c.RatingDomainModels)
  .OrderBy(c => c.CompanyStatId).Skip(page * pgeSize)
  .Take(pgeSize).Select(csr => new CompanyStatRepo {
     prop1 = csr.prop1,
     prop2 = csr.prop2,
     ...
     RatingDomainModels = csr.RatingDomainModels.ToList()
  }).ToList();
```

I don't know the real structure of your classes, but this is the basic idea.